# Evaluate $\iiint_D (x^2+y^2+z^2)\,dx\,dy\,dz$, where $D$ is the region delimited by the planes $x+y+z=a,\; x=0,\;y=0$ and $z=0$.

Tags: integration

The problem is as follows:

> Evaluate $\iiint_D (x^2+y^2+z^2)\,dx\,dy\,dz$, where $D$ is the region delimited by the planes $x+y+z=a,\; x=0,\;y=0$ and $z=0$.

The problem is that I don't know the limits am supposed to use in order for me to handle this question. If there is need of writing a sketch, that will be highly appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! The community here prefers/expects questions to include something of what the asker knows. (What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? etc) This information helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) telling you things you already know or using techniques with which you are unfamiliar. (Plus, it helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you.) Please [edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3382775/edit) to add such details; comments are easily overlooked.

Comment: For each $y,z$, $0\le x\le a-y-z$. For each $z$, $0\le y\le a-z$. Finally, $0\le z\le a$.

Comment: By symmetry $$\iiint_D x^2\ dx\ dy\ dz=\iiint_D y^2\ dx\ dy\ dz =\iiint_D z^2\ dx\ dy\ dz.$$  So if $I$ is the value of each integral above, your answer is $3I$.  Calculating $I$ should be relatively easy.

Comment: How will the working be like?